# Woocommerce Checkout Errors Edit

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the error messages coming from the checkout page.

Can anyone help me?

[image]

I can see that the strings are in the woocommerce.pot file.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question and clarify your problem description. If possible add some code of what you tried. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you want to change? What is the replacement? Your question is just too vague… so unclear. Please try to clarify adding some more details… Please remember that people can't guess what is in your mind.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can, just add a filter to the hook `woocommerce_checkout_required_field_notice`.

```
function filter_woocommerce_checkout_required_field_notice( $sprintf, $field_label ) {
    $my_custom_notice = '' . $field_label . ' and my custom notice!';
    return sprintf( __( '%s is a required field.', 'woocommerce' ), $my_custom_notice ); 
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_required_field_notice', 'filter_woocommerce_checkout_required_field_notice', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the content of error box to something like "Field with * are required".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#Id_of_Error_Container").html('<p class="red">Fields with * are required</p>');
});
</script>
```

Add this to footer.php and change #Id_of_Error_Container with div id of error box.